# How to "PERFORM" CTE queries in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, common-table-expression

I tried to simulate my problem in the code example below. In the code below, I am doing a `select * from test` in a procedure. As we know, we must use the `perform` keyword for this. This works great:

```
perform * from test;
```

However, if I try to rewrite that simple query as a CTE, I cannot get it working. I am getting a syntax error.

```
with test_as_cte as(select * from test) perform * from test_as_cte;
```

Is this possible? What is the correct syntax? I tried several alternatives and going through documentation, but without any success so far.

(Please note that this is just an example to explain my problem. I know the queries do not really make any sense.)

```
create table test
(
    key int primary key  
);

create function test() returns trigger as
$$
begin
    raise notice 'hello there';
    -- this does work
    perform * from test;
    -- this doesn't work
    with test_as_cte as(select * from test) perform * from test_as_cte;
    return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger test after insert on test for each row execute procedure test();

insert into test(key) select 1;
```

Comment: Consider the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71040855/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter >>Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but discard the result, for example when calling a function that has side-effects but no useful result value. 
So the whole perform clause does not make sense.  in this case.
so it's same like
`begin
    raise notice 'hello there';
    return new;
end`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try:

```
perform (with test_as_cte as(select * from test) select * from test_as_cte);
```

I would never think you might need CTE and ignore the result, but if you need, thinking of perform as of "select no return" logic leads to above semantics. or `perform * from (CTE)` or alike

Comment: Thank you. That works indeed. The problem is, I abstracted a bit too much. I will ask a new question.

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes apparently :). I will add it later today. Thanks again.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908442/postgres-plpgsql-with-perform-data-modifying-cte-queries