# Postgres plpgsql with PERFORM data-modifying CTE queries

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

I tried to simulate my problem in the code example below. In the code below, I am doing a `delete from test2` in a procedure. This works great:

However, in my case, this `delete` is part of a rather complex CTE with several updates and inserts (there are no selects so I add a dummy `select 1` as main query). Let's simulate this as this:

```
with my_cte as(delete from test2) select 1
```

Now, as we know, we have to use the `perform` keyword to execute this:

```
perform (with my_cte as(delete from test2) select 1);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level
```

Is this a limitation of plpgsql?

(Please note that this is just an example to explain my problem. I know the queries do not really make any sense.)

```
create table test
(
    key int primary key  
);

create table test2
(
    key int primary key
);

create function test() returns trigger as
$$
begin
    raise notice 'hello there';
    -- this does work
    delete from test2;
    -- this doesn't work
    perform (with my_cte as(delete from test2) select 1);
    return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger test after insert on test for each row execute procedure test();

insert into test(key) select 1;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRA6sSXjJRk5cj6GMPJH1ExEfKcujc1e_C4UFsHM6eMAbA@mail.gmail.com have you read the thread above? I'd say it is a limitation. It would be easier if you would share the real problem - maybe there is a simplier solution then performing CTW with data manipulation

Comment: Reason why I am using CTEs: I could indeed have several separate INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE queries, but it is (much) more performant to pass results around between CTEs with returning ... at the end of the query. The alternative is fetching the data and storing in local data structures in the plpgsq procedures, to use it in the following queries.

Comment: So, in my opinion, these kind of queries are not really `useless`, as stated in your mailing link. Thank you for that link by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CTE for combining several DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE returning queries. And you dont need perform for it, eg:

```
t=# begin; do $$ begin with d as (delete from s133 returning *) insert into s133 select * from d; raise info '%',(select count(1) from s133);
end; $$; commit;
BEGIN
Time: 0.135 ms
INFO:  4
DO
Time: 0.469 ms
COMMIT
Time: 0.887 ms
t=# select count(1) from s133;
 count
-------
     4
(1 row)
```

here I delete four rows and in CTE insert them back

Comment: Clever. Instead of having several `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` CTEs and a dummy `select 1`, I could move the last CTE query to the main query.

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, you can neither nest such a `WITH` clause in a subselect, not can you do

```
WITH cte AS (...)
PERFORM 1;
```

One solution would be to use `SELECT ... INTO dummy` instead of `PERFORM` and ignore the result.

But I don't see why you cannot code the `DELETE`s, `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s in your function with several SQL statements rather than bundling them into CTEs.

If you try to protect yourself from concurrent data modification, use a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction so that all your statements operate on the same snapshot of the database.

Comment: Reason why I am using CTEs: I could indeed have several separate `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` queries, but it is (much) more performant to pass results around between CTEs with `returning ...` at the end of the query. The alternative is fetching the data and storing in local data structures in the plpgsq procedures, to use it in the following queries.

Comment: Ok, then use `SELECT` instead of `PERFORM` and you are set.