# How to "PERFORM" a CTE query returning multiple rows/columns?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, database-performance, multiple-select-query

As a follow-up to this question:

- [How to "PERFORM" CTE queries in PL/pgSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906375/how-to-perform-cte-queries-in-pl-pgsql)

I try:

```
perform (with test_as_cte as(select * from myTable) select * from test_as_cte);
```

But get the following error:

> ```
> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: subquery must return only one column
> Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at PERFORM
> ```

If I replace `*` with `myCol` in the above code there is no error.

However, I need to do realistic performance testing with the CTE and return multiple columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WITH` query enclosed in parentheses is treated like a sub-select. It works fine the way you have it as long as it returns a **single value** (one column of one row). Else you must treat it as subquery and call it like this (inside a PL/pgSQL code block!):

```
PERFORM * FROM (with test_as_cte as (select * from b2) select * from test_as_cte t) sub;
```

Or just:

```
PERFORM FROM (<any SELECT query>) sub;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html)

> `PERFORM` ***`query`***;
>
> This executes ***`query`*** and discards the result. Write the query
> the same way you would write an SQL `SELECT` command, but replace the
> initial keyword `SELECT` with `PERFORM`. For `WITH` queries, use
> `PERFORM` and then place the query in parentheses. (In this case, the
> query can only return one row.)

I think this could be clearer. I'll suggest a fix for the documentation.

Comment: NOTE to reader:  At least on my system, PERFORM will not work in isolation and I must surround it with all the other elements ....  DO $proc$
DECLARE
  StartTime timestamptz;
  EndTime timestamptz;
  Delta double precision;
BEGIN
  StartTime := clock_timestamp();
 
 PERFORM * FROM (with test_as_cte as (select * from myTable) select * from test_as_cte t) sub;


  EndTime := clock_timestamp();
  Delta := 1000 * ( extract(epoch from EndTime) - extract(epoch from StartTime) );
  RAISE NOTICE 'Duration in millisecs=%', Delta;
END;
$proc$;

Comment: Yeah, guess it makes sense to remind casual readers that we are talking about a PL/pgSQL code block here.